# DateTime validation errors in client side validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime

I'm trying to use the custom DateTime format of: `"MMM/dd/yyyy"` in an MVC5 project. However, when trying to submit the form, certain browsers (e.g. Safari) throw a validation error that state: *"The field Contact Date must be a date"*.

Model:

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   [Display(Name = "ContactDateLabel", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   public DateTime? ClientDateStart { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ClientDateStart, new { @class = "form-control noflex", @data_provide = "datepicker", @data_date_format = "M/dd/yyyy" })
```

I hope I'm not missing something completely obvious!

Comment: `@data_date_format = "M/dd/yyyy"` looks wrong in View... no? nice dog btw :)

Comment: That's for the DateTime picker, and it works as expected (to match the MMM) - See: [This screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/149192/datetime.jpg)